# Question about switch

Tags: java

I'm a java beginner, so what's wrong with this code:

```
switch(keycode) {
    case Keyboard.KEY_UP || Keyboard.KEY_DOWN: 
}
```

I gives me the following error message:

```
bad operand types for binary operator '||'
  first type:  int
  second type: int
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are applying the logical or operator `||` to integers which is not allowed. You can apply the logical operators to only boolean operands.

Since you want to execute the same case block when `keycode` is either `Keyboard.KEY_UP` or `Keyboard.KEY_DOWN` use a fall through case block as:

```
switch(keycode) {

    case Keyboard.KEY_UP:     /* fall through */
    case Keyboard.KEY_DOWN:   /* Common code when keycode is either 
                                 KEY_UP or KEY_DOWN */
                              break;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
switch(keycode) 
{    

    case Keyboard.KEY_UP:
    case Keyboard.KEY_DOWN: 
        //  code to run...
        break;

}
```

See [The `switch` Statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: @cyrianox: Don't call yourself stupid for misunderstanding some syntax. Even the pros do that now and then, and learning to program takes a long time.

Answer (score 3):

You understand that || means "or" but you don't have a full understanding. || is a *comparator* between two boolean variables **only**

Something is either true || false. It cannot be chalk || cheese.

The switch statement is a integer comparator. You could change

```
int number =3
switch(number)
    case 1: one(); break;
    case 2: two(); break;
    case 3: three(); break;
```

to

```
if(number == 1) one();
else if(number ==2) two();
else if(number == 3) three();
```

It looks like what you are trying to do is

`if(number == 1 || number == 2)` where you will notice `number == 1` is either true or false and `number == 2` is either true or false.

switch statements are useful when, as in accepted answer, you can perform several cases before breaking out of the structure with a `break;`

Comment: +1 for the explanation of _why_ Java doesn't allow `||` in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Change to

```
switch (keycode) {
case Keyboard.KEY_UP:
case Keyboard.KEY_DOWN:
    // Do something, then
    break;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(keycode) {
case Keyboard.KEY_UP:
case Keyboard.KEY_DOWN:
// code here
break;
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with switch (at least not in Java). You'll have to do

```
switch(keycode) {
 case Keyboard.KEY_UP:
 case Keyboard.KEY_DOWN:
   doKeyStuff();
   break;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same behavior for both values, don't use || operator, just have the first case fall through to the second:

```
switch(keycode) {
  case Keyboard.KEY_UP:
  case Keyboard.KEY_DOWN:
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a logical operation on a number.

You can write this

```
switch(keycode) {
    case Keyboard.KEY_UP | Keyboard.KEY_DOWN: 
}
```

However this will not do what you might expect as keycode would have to be the combination of these values.  What you intended is likely to be

```
switch(keycode) {
    case Keyboard.KEY_UP: case Keyboard.KEY_DOWN: 
}
```

This will match either values.